# Scala collections contains not using ==?

Tags: scala, collections

Consider the following code:

```
scala> case class Foo(s:String, t:String, r:String) {
     |    def == (f:Foo) = s == f.s && t == f.t
     | }
defined class Foo

scala> val f1 = Foo("s", "t", "r")
f1: Foo = Foo(s,t,r)

scala> val f2 = Foo("s", "t", "r1")
f2: Foo = Foo(s,t,r1)

scala> f1 == f2
res24: Boolean = true

scala> Array(f1) contains (f2)
res25: Boolean = false
```

I was under the impression that `contains` uses `==` as defined above. Did I misunderstand?

Version: Scala-2-10-2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is, that you don't override, but overload the `==` method. It has to be defined as `def == (a: Any): Boolean`, because in java and scala you can compare any two objects. But in case classes this method is final. You can however override `equals` with the same signature, because `==` is just an alias for `equals`. But overriding these methods in case classes should be avoided, because the definition of equality on case classes is, that every single value has to be equal on both instances.

Comment: So probably a better solution is to not use `case` class.

Answer (score 1):

To exclude `r` from case magic just define `Foo(s,t)(r)`.

```
scala> case class Foo(s: String, t: String)(r: String)
defined class Foo

scala> Array(Foo("a","b")("c")) contains Foo("a","b")("d")
res6: Boolean = true
```

You use case classes because they automate stuff that's easy to get wrong.

Your conclusion that you shouldn't use case class because you got equality wrong is kind of the wrong conclusion.